# Tool to validate Solr index

Tags: solr, lucidworks

Is there a tool to validate Solr index and can tell if its corrupted? I have googled but could not find any tool. Basically what I need is a software kind of thing that can walk through the index and find discrepancies

Comment: Have you tried [Luke](https://code.google.com/p/luke/) ?

Comment: if the answer helped, accept it to close the thread

Answer (score 2):

### CheckIndex

[CheckIndex](http://solr.pl/en/2011/01/17/checkindex-for-the-rescue/) is a tool available in the Lucene library, which allows you to check the files and create new segments that do not contain problematic entries.

### Command

```
java -ea:org.apache.lucene... org.apache.lucene.index.CheckIndex INDEX_PATH -fix
```